# Concatenating items from two lists to form n-grams using python

Tags: python, concatenation

My goal is to join k with each item in k1 to form a list of bi-grams.

```
k='john'
k1=['john', 'is', 'sleeping']

My attempt
y=[(x +',', k) for x in k1]

My output
[('john,', 'john'), ('is,', 'john'), ('sleeping,', 'john')]

Desired output
[('john', 'john'), ('is' , 'john'), ('sleeping' , 'john')]
```

I just want to get rid of the comma after the first word in each bigram.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: So what do you think the `+','` is doing?

Comment: You are not concatenating, you are building new tuples. No need to add a `','` string here, this is syntax, not text!

Comment: Thanks for the insight Martijn Pieters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k='john'
k1=['john', 'is', 'sleeping']
print [(i, k) for i in k1]
```

**Output**

```
[('john', 'john'), ('is', 'john'), ('sleeping', 'john')]
```

You can do cartesian product with `k1` and `k` if you have more elements in both `k` and `k1`

```
k=['john']
k1=['john', 'is', 'sleeping']
from itertools import product
print [item for item in product(k1, k)]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is so close, you added it yourself. Remove the `+ ','` and you're done!

```
y=[(x, k) for x in k1]
```

I think you won't need it, but for the sake of this answer's completion, here's a demo:

```
>>> k='john'
>>> k1=['john', 'is', 'sleeping']
>>> y=[(x, k) for x in k1]
>>> y
[('john', 'john'), ('is', 'john'), ('sleeping', 'john')]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`. I prefer using python inbuilts.

```
k=['john']
k1=['john', 'is', 'sleeping']

zip(k1, k*len(k1))


#output:
[('john', 'john'), ('is', 'john'), ('sleeping', 'john')]
```